# STATS: Probability less than sample size, given a percentage

Tags: probability, statistics

Please help with this question. I know the answer is 0.0002 but I don't know how to get it.

In March, 2016 it was reported by the Fair Work Ombudsman that 51% of employers in Australia were not paying their staff the correct wages. A random sample of 85 employers was selected. The probability that less than 27 of these employers were not paying their staff the correct wages was...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I think this is a flawed problem, requiring an approximation and an error to get the answer provided. Willing to give OP a pass on this one.

Answer (score 0):

On this site, you are ordinarily supposed to show what you have tried. But I believe this is a flawed question. Strictly speaking, it is not possible to answer with the information given. You need to make assumptions. Furthermore, in my view, to get 0.0002, you need to make an approximation and an error. So I don't wonder that you are puzzled.

**Exact Binomial Answer, Using Assumptions.** Suppose we take it as fact that $p = P(\text{Incorrect payment}) = .51,$ as in the Ombudsman's report. Also, let $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 85,\, p=.51).$ 
Then it is possible to compute $P(X < 27) = P(X \le 26),$ using the formula
for the PDF of the binomial distribution. The exact value from R statistical
software is 0.00011 (to five places).

```
pbinom(26, 85, .51)
## 0.0001106594
```

If you are intended to use some kind of software, perhaps you can work out
how to use it to get the same answer.

**Normal Approximation, with and without Continuity Correction.** If you are intended to use a normal
approximation then $X \stackrel{aprs}{\sim}\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma),$
where $\mu = np = 85(.51)$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{85(.51)(.49)}.$
Using a continuity correction you would compute $P(X \le 26.5),$
possibly standardizing $X$ and using printed normal tables. The difficulty is
that the resulting standard score is beyond the scope of most printed
normal tables I have seen. An exact normal value using software rounds
to 0.0001. If you ignore the continuity correction to find $P(X \le 27),$ you get a result that rounds to 0.0002.

```
mu = 85*.51;  sg = sqrt(mu*.49)
pnorm(26.5, mu, sg)
## 0.0001280859
pnorm(27, mu, sg)
## 0.0001944362
```

Below is a graph of the lower tail of the relevant binomial distribution along with
the density function of the best-fitting normal distribution. You want
the probability (essentially to small too show on the graph) to the left
of the vertical red line.

[image]